# Davis.js as AMD module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Can i use davisjs as AMD module with requirejs? I tried, but maybe i forgot something in require config?

```
requirejs([
   "jquery",
   "davis"
],
function   ($, routing) {
    var app = routing(function () {
        this.get('/welcome/:name', function (req) {
            alert("Hello " + req.params['name']);
        });
    });
}
```

This works:

```
var app = Davis(function () {..});
```

Comment: what error do you get? please also post your require.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like someone has a case of the Missing Shim. You need to configure RequireJS to adapt the non-AMD-compatible library into an AMD module like this:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    Davis: 'script/davis'
  },
  shim: {
    Davis: {
      exports: 'Davis'
    }
  }
});

require([
  "Davis"
], function (davis) {
  console.log("Davis?", davis);
});
```

More info in [RequireJS documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

---

Invoking `Davis()` directly works since it's available in the global scope; it's just not "registered" as an AMD module: that why it's `undefined` when requested by RequireJS.